# The quest for a succint, readable expression of Next in a sequence

Tags: c#

I have a need to express something like this:

```
while(bytesToWrite > 0)
{
    // get the NEXT location to write from a Key/Value collection of locations

    // read a packet from a file at the specified location

    // write some bytes to the packet

    bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten
}
```

This was my first attempt:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<long, long>() { .. }
...

while(bytesToWrite > 0)
{
    var pin = dictionary.Take(1).First();
    Debug.Print(pin.Key.ToString() + ", " + pin.Value.ToString());

   // Write the bytes using Key and Value for location information.

    dictionary = dictionary.Skip(1)
    bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten;
}
```

But it doesn't look terribly efficient to me.  It looks like I'm making a new collection each time through the loop, just to peel off a single item, and the `Take(1).First()` and `dictionary = dictionary.Skip(1)` syntax is a bit awkward.

If I put my original collection in a `LinkedList`, I can do this:

```
var map = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<long, long>>(dictionary);
...
var pin = map.First;
while (pin != null && bytesToWrite > 0)
{
    // Value.Key and Value.Value??
    Debug.Print(pin.Value.Key.ToString() + ", " + pin.Value.Value.ToString());

    // Write the bytes

    pin = pin.Next;
    bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten;
}
```

Eww.  `Value.Key` and `Value.Value` is not exactly intuitive.

I can write a couple of wrapper classes, like so:

```
public class StateList<T>
{
    LinkedList<T> list;
    LinkedListNode<T> currentNode;

    public StateList(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        list = new LinkedList<T>(source);
    }

    public StateList<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new StateList<T>(source);
    }

    public T First
    {
        get
        {
            var node = list.First;
            return Value(node);
        }
    }

    public T Last
    {
        get
        {
            var node = list.Last;
            return Value(node);
        }
    }

    public T Next
    {
        get
        {
            var node = currentNode.Next;
            return Value(node);
        }
    }

    public T Previous
    {
        get
        {
            var node = currentNode.Previous;
            return Value(node);
        }
    }

    public T Value(LinkedListNode<T> node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            var value = node.Value;
            currentNode = node;
            return value;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}

public static class StateList
{
    public static StateList<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new StateList<T>(source);
    }
}
```

and get the code look like this:

```
var map = StateList.Create(dictionary);
...
var pin = map.First;
while (bytesToWrite > 0)
{
    // Ah, that's better.
    Debug.Print(pin.Key.ToString() + ", " + pin.Value.ToString());

    // Write the bytes

    // Pin is taken from the map, not from the previous pin.
    pin = map.Next;
    bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten;
}
```

Ah, that's much better.  The question is, is all that ceremony really worth it?  I feel like I'm missing something simple and obvious.

I'd also like comments on the relative merit of the StateList class, whether it is a satisfactory approach from a good practices viewpoint, or a terrible abomination.

Comment: Why can't you simply use a `foreach` over the `Dictionary`? If you need to end the loop early due to `bytesToWrite`, you could just use `break`.

Comment: @svick: I admit that the example is somewhat contrived (although it is based on real-world code).  This is more of a language syntax exercise, using a simple state machine.  I tried doing it with `yield` `return`, but got wrapped around the axle over the generic definitions, and it still returns a collection anyway, rather than the next element in the sequence.

Comment: You might have misunderstood me. I'm not proposing doing anything complicated like `yield return`. Just use `foreach (var pin in dictionary)` and it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @svick: I refactored my existing code using your suggestion, and it turned out cleaner than any of my other tries, so it appears that the state machine approach is not going to be worth it.  If you post an answer with one of my code samples above so modified, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a `foreach` over the `Dictionary`, combined with a `break` for the `bytesToWrite` condition.

```
foreach (var pin in dictionary)
{
    if (bytesToWrite <= 0)
        break;

    Debug.Print(pin.Key + ", " + pin.Value);

    // Write the bytes using Key and Value for location information.

    bytesToWrite -= bytesWritten;
}
```